# smallest javascript framework

Tags: javascript, frameworks

What javascript framework like jQuery or prototype is the smallest and has DOM manipulation and animation? I'm looking for something that can be used to build custom "web-widgets" without adding a large footprint on the site size. I absolutely need DOM query by css selectors. Is there anything like this around 5kb minified?

**EDIT**

should have stated that I need CSS3 selectors cross platform including IE7+

Comment: [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) are native to modern browsers so that's no footprint at all!

Comment: Without knowing the details of your scenario, I would suggest that using a CDN supplied jQuery.js might give you the benefit of already being cached on the device in many cases.

Comment: @JamesAllardice. But doesn't exist in old browsers... so you do need a js framework.

Comment: at what versions of each major browser was that added to? maybe I just won't support it

Comment: @LordZardeck - The obvious one is that it's not supported below IE8. [See the full list here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).

Comment: not only that, but they only support the css specification supported by the browser. I should have stated that I need CSS3 selectors. i'll update my answer

Comment: @LordZardeck - How about Sizzle? See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just can answer this question without a link...

Read the [*Comparison of JavaScript frameworks*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) in **Wikipedia**

The second row there is the size of each framework.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't specify browser versions or anything, the answer is you don't need any framework. All the current frameworks are written on top of standard JS, so you can just use the functionality directly, and querySelector(All) can handle selector lookups for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet may be to use [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), which is what jQuery uses internally as its selector engine. It supports almost all CSS3 selectors, and the website states:

> Only 4KB minified and gzipped

The `Sizzle` function returns an array of elements. For example:

```
var elems = Sizzle(".myElems");
```

Comment: what would I use for animation then?

Comment: I don't know... your question only asked for CSS selector support!

Comment: **?!** _"What javascript framework like jQuery or prototype is the smallest and has DOM manipulation **and animation**?"_

Comment: @gdoron - Ah, yeah. LordZardeck - sorry!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at zepto for instance :

http://zeptojs.com/

Comment: well you did not state IE compatibility at first place.

Comment: by the way one reason jQuery is that heavy is because it maitains IE compatibility , whereas a lot of jQuery like frameworks are not as much tested against IE.

Answer (score 0):

maybe http://xuijs.com/ could help you or http://quojs.tapquo.com/